# How combine min and max with date

Tags: sql-server

I want my code combine the date like (Format is 2/4/19) but I em using min  in TimeIn I don't know how to solve this (this is the example that I want to display 2/4/19 8:00)

```
Select  A.EmpID [X_TMSHT_EMPID],
        A.[RecordDate] [X_TMSHT_APPLY],
        CONCAT(A.[RecordDate], (MIN(IIF(ISNULL(CHARINDEX('I', A.[Entries], 0), -1) > 0, SUBSTRING(A.[Entries], LEN(A.[Entries]) - 5, 5), NULL)))) AS [X_TMSHT_TIMEIN]
FROM Employees  [B] 
inner JOIN [DTR Upload] [A] ON B.EmployeeNo = A.EmpID 
where B.LastName + ','+B.FirstName + ','+ B.MiddleName LIKE 'CRUZ,MA. KIMBERLY,CASTILLO%'
GROUP by B.LastName, B.FirstName, B.MiddleName,A.EmpID, A.[recordDate]
order by A.[recordDate] asc, B.LastName + ','+B.FirstName + ','+ B.MiddleName asc
```

this is my result

```
..X_TMSHT_EMPID.......||..X_TMSHT_APPLY..............||......X_TMSHT_TIMEIN........
001693............... ||    2019-05-03 00:00:00.000..||May  3 2019 12:00AM12:08
```

but I want is

```
..X_TMSHT_EMPID.......||..X_TMSHT_APPLY..............||......X_TMSHT_TIMEIN........
001693............... ||    2019-05-03 00:00:00.000..||05/03/2019  12:00:00
```

Comment: [This link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/) might help. `convert(varchar, date_column_name, 22)`

Comment: You should format the time in your front end application

Comment: how can you please teach me?

Comment: why you are using `CONCAT` in `X_TMSHT_TIMEIN`. Can you please post your input data.

Comment: Also what is the value of `A.[Entries]`.